How to increase resource limits for ephemeral storage on GKE
We've got a few batch processing jobs running on GKE/Kubernetes that need anywhere between 30-250Gi of temporary disk space to execute. In order to make them work without (slow) PVCs, we've now added local SSDs to the node pools they're running on and are trying to just mount that as an emptyDir.
If I set the resource requests for the relevant containers using resources.limit.ephemeral-storage, the following error message is returned:

Invalid value: "100Gi": must be less than or equal to ephemeral-storage limit of 10Gi

To lift this limit in the cluster, I've tried to set a ResourceQuota like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: storage-resources
spec:
  hard:
    requests.ephemeral-storage: "10Gi"
    limits.ephemeral-storage: "360Gi"

No help, same error. Then I tried to set a LimitRange object like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: local-ssd-ephemeral-storage
spec:
  limits:
    - default:
        ephemeral-storage: 300Gi
      defaultRequest:
        ephemeral-storage: 5Gi
      type: Container

Also no help. Has anyone managed to deal with this limit?
